# Need to implement RESTful web services in Struts2 and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, struts2

I am currently working on a web application that is based on Strtus2, Spring, open JPA and LDAP.

Now client wants us to develop RESTful api for this system so that other websites or application can integrate with it.

This task has been assigned to me and I clearly have no idea from where to start.

I have done my research and found out that, there is a plugin `struts2-rest` and for Spring there are several different ways.

More to that most of the example I have been seen are using Maven, but our project does not use that.

So, I just need a direction to start this thing.

Comment: This is OT. BTW, you're not forced to use something related to Struts2. Just stick with Java EE standards (JAX RS), if you can.

Comment: @AndreaLigios This seems to be the best one, thanks for the help will try this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Struts2 you can implement RESTful api via struts2-rest-plugin. The starting point is [REST Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/).

> #### [Setting Up](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#setting-up)
>
> Assuming you have a normal Struts 2 application, all you need to do
> for this REST demo is to add the following two plugins:
>
> ```
> Struts 2 Rest Plugin
> Struts 2 Convention Plugin
> ```
>
> Note, you can download the jars for these plugins from Maven Central
> Configuration ( struts.xml )
>
> Just dropping the plugin's into your application may not produce
> exactly the desired effect. There are a couple of considerations. The
> first consideration is whether you want to have any non-RESTful URL's
> coexisting with your RESTful URL's. We'll show two configurations. The
> first assumes all you want to do is REST. The second assumes you want
> to keep other non-RESTful URL's alive in the same Struts 2
> application.

---

In the [Home](http://struts.apache.org/docs/) of Struts2 docs you'll find everything necessary to start developing Struts2 application.

### Resources:

- [Struts 2 Rest Showcase Webapp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-rest-showcase)
- [Creating java web applications with AngularJS and Struts2](http://www.jgeppert.com/2015/05/creating-java-web-applications-with-angularjs-and-struts2/)
- [Struts 2 + REST Web Service Integration Example](http://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-rest-web-service-integration-example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried it out and after adding 4 libraries the web application is not working correctly. For every action I am hitting, I am getting exception and when I checked the logs, I saw that all the methods got a .index() suffix in them. I mean the server is thinking that, the method is not execute().index() instead of execute(). Any idea what to do with that ?

Comment: @Raddix I suggest you to download a working project from the official site, and try to run it in your environment.

Comment: Just did sorry for not doing that earlier.