# Problems with strust2 rest plugin and internet Explorer

Tags: rest, struts2

I have a problem with struts2 rest plugin, it only happens using internet explorer. In the redirect phase after a post of a form the application goes wrong

> 14:10:29,984 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation]
>   (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-12) Exception processing the result.:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>     org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultContentTypeHandlerManager.getExtensionIfPresent(DefaultContentTypeHandlerManager.java:234)
>   [struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.37.jar:2.3.37]  at
>     org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultContentTypeHandlerManager.getHandlerForResponse(DefaultContentTypeHandlerManager.java:132)
>   [struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.37.jar:2.3.37]   ....

Comment: There's no redirect phase when using rest plugin. If you need to learn more about struts2-rest-plugin then read https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363857/573032

Comment: Or the plugin docs, which seem more thorough.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the request being made etc. it's impossible to even begin.